# Capturing combined keyboard inputs in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am looking for a solution in Flex where I can capture a combination of keyboard inputs such as: [CTRL] + A + B

That is, pressing the CTRL key and the user presses two keys (instead of the usual one).

I can capture the event when somebody keys: [CTRL] + A with the following code:

```
if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 65)
```

How would I capture an additional key so that the event is captured when somebody presses CTRL, A and B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to listen to KEY_DOWN as well as KEY_UP, and use these to set an internal flag denoting whether A or B is currently pressed. - let's call it `a_isDown:boolean` and `b_isDown:boolean`.

Then, in your `KEY_DOWN` event,

```
if (event.ctrlKey && ((event.keyCode == 65 && b_isDown) || 
   (event.keyCode == 66 && a_isDown))) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks Steve.  I'll use this method.